# Where are my other video formats

Tags: export

[image: Where are my other video formats]

i update blender to 2.79 and the movie formats are gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select *FFmpeg video* and a panel named *Encoding* will appear. It may appear at the bottom, so it's possible you'll have to drag it to reorder. To do that, just grab the 8 dots at the far right of the panel caption, and drag it to where you want it.

[image]